# Is Prism 4.0 compatible with WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, prism

Does anyone know if the latest drop (i beleive its 6) of prism v4.0 is compatible with WP7?

Actually really all i am interested in currently is the MVVM implementation / support that comes with prism 4.0 ...

So would this be compatible with WP7?

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this post](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=211059) on the PRISM forums, there is no WP7 support at this time, but they do hope to support it in a future release. In the meantime, you may want to look at [Phone 7](http://phone7.codeplex.com/) (a PRISM April CTP WP7 port).

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, it is not currently supported but there are ports being developed. There is also a port of MEF which you should be able to use to solve many of the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Prism is rather heavy-weight for WP7.

Two lighter options are:

MVVM-light: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Caliburn Micro:  http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

Caliburn is most Prism-like in that it support DI through a container, event aggregation, view discovery and a pile of other features.  it's a "convention over configuration" approach, which takes so getting used to if you're used to Unity, but it does grow on you.

it's event aggregation isn't great but it is very easy to pull out the Prism EventAggregator and wire it into Caliburn Micro as a service.

I've written 2 phone apps using Caliburn Micro, it's a great framework.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is Prism support for wp7  (All be it slightly altered) located at msdn. 
And there is a project template located in the downloads here [Bindable Application Bar](http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/releases/view/80041)

It does leave out some of the more heavy weight pieces of Prism. I didn't read the book in its entirety but heres a few things changed for wp7.

- The concept of a Shell to inject regions into (there is a DataTemplateSelector that facilitates this somewhat)
- Composite Event (Uses Composite commands instead)

Also to add to earier commens about how heavy weight prism is. Nothing says you have to use everything offered in every application. The general idea is orginization of complexity and ease of extendibility. If you know about what prism offers in other apps why not leverage what you know to make your life easier.